# WDS Disconnected! on React, Webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I got WDS disconnection error on my application.

on webpack.config.js

```
entry: {
    App: [
        'webpack-dev-server/client?https://127.0.0.0:3001',
        'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
        './src/index.js'
    ]
},

devServer: {
    inline: true,
    port: 3001,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    contentBase: __dirname + '/public/',
    disableHostCheck: true,
},
```

on package.json

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
  "start": "webpack-dev-server --hot --host 0.0.0.0"
},
```

I'm using proxypass on nginx, and request is sent to

https://aaa.test.com:7777/sockjs-node/info?t=1525090493047

if I remove port number like

https://aaa.test.com/sockjs-node/info?t=1525090493047

I can see some text, but with port number it goes to error page.

On nginx setting,

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3001;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

Did I do something wrong?